# Can't Access Local HDD with Linux Live USB?

Tags: usb

I'm using a Linux USB to try and get into an old computer.

I've done so in the past with others by going into the Windows OS folder, however when I try to do it on this PC I can open other local folders but not the Windows OS folder. I get an input output error and it says that the HDD is mounted as Read only.

I have tried a mix of mount commands but nothing seems to work?

Comment: This site support Ubuntu and official flavors, and we are not a generic Linux support site.   If you are using a Ubuntu or official flavor, please tell us which and your release.  If the windows is using fast-boot; it's file system may be unclean (ie. part of file-system data is still in fast-boot-hibernate file on not yet written to file-system) so it's unsafe to write in this mode (your logs will show this as a likely cause if you look).  For help here though we need to know how it relates to Ubuntu.